Jobs Managed by Laravel Horizon Disappearing from Redis When "DB Saved on Disk" Logs Appear
Issue:
I'm experiencing a critical issue where jobs managed by Laravel Horizon suddenly disappear from Redis. This occurs simultaneously with numerous "DB Saved on Disk" logs appearing in my Redis container logs. Whenever I see these logs, all my jobs vanish from Redis.
Details:
Redis Configuration (redis.conf):
`appendonly yes

appendfsync everysec
save 900 1
save 300 10
save 60 10000
save ""
`
Environment:
Laravel App in a Docker container
Redis running in a Docker container

Problem Description:
I have configured Redis with appendonly yes and appendfsync everysec to ensure data persistence. The save configurations are commented out, and save "" is used to disable RDB snapshots. Despite this setup, I frequently see multiple "DB Saved on Disk" logs in quick succession in my Redis container logs, and this is when all the jobs managed by Laravel Horizon disappear from Redis.redis logs
Steps to Reproduce:
Configure Redis with the provided redis.conf settings.
Run Laravel Horizon to manage jobs.
Monitor Redis container logs.
Observe the disappearance of jobs when "DB Saved on Disk" logs appear.

Attempted Solutions:
I have tried different Redis configurations, including disabling appendonly and enabling various RDB snapshot settings. Unfortunately, the issue persists across different configuration modes.

Questions:
What could be causing Redis to log "DB Saved on Disk" despite having RDB snapshots disabled?
Is there a known issue with the appendonly and appendfsync settings that could lead to job loss in Redis?
What steps can I take to prevent jobs from disappearing in Redis?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
